# Access photos with AssetLibraryPhotosViewer

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, alassetslibrary

I'm trying out this code: http://github.com/akpw/AssetLibraryPhotosViewer to access photos on my iPhone.

However when I run the application, I get an alert that says the application is trying to access my photos - and then I can allow this or decline.

Can I disable this when using the AssetLibrary, or does this message always appear?

If I can't turn this off, and I press "Don't Allow", can I still make the app access my photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from answer above. This will appear once. If you allow access then it will not show again and you will have access to the photo's. If you disallow it then you will not be allowed to access this and the alert dialog will not appear again.

This permission can be changed at any time by the user in the settings app (Under Location and Privacy, or a variation of that.) This has been around since iOS 6 I believe.

You are never able to programtically state that access has been granted, the system handles the permissions which are shown to the user.

Comment: Okey. Thank you. I thought it was possible to access media library without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security feature of the OS that cannot be disabled. If a user does not give your app permission to access the photo library your app *will not* be able to access any photos. Given this ability your app should be able to handle the situation gracefully from a UI/UX perspective.

For more information take a look at this guide from Apple about iOS security guidelines (page 47 takes about accessing personal data) [iOS Security](https://www.apple.com/privacy/docs/iOS_Security_Guide_Oct_2014.pdf)